# SSRS Sql query with when clause and input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, case-when

I'm trying to get a SQL query working in SSRS.
This query is executed when I execute my report in SSRS. It is a select which simply populates my dataset.
I want to have the Date at the moment of the report execution on first execution and then I want the user to be able to input a different date if needed thus the need for the parameter.
Here it is :

```
Select contrat from contrats ctr, 
INNER JOIN structure rs ON rs.id = ctr.id 
INNER JOIN structure_members rsm ON rsm.id_structure = rs.id_structure
where 
(((Date(ctr.date) = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN Date(Now) END) or
(Date(rs.endDate) = CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN Date(Now) END)
GROUP BY crt.contrat
```

Don't mind any syntax error, I just simplified my query to get to the point : is this possible?
Can I do a case when end like this?

```
`CASE WHEN ? IS NULL THEN Date(Now)`
```

The ? is a date that I input such as 2014-08-04. The value could be null if I wanted to. That's why I'm trying to check if it is null then complete the query using Date(now) instead.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select contrat from contrats ctr 
INNER JOIN structure rs ON rs.id = ctr.id 
INNER JOIN structure_members rsm ON rsm.id_structure = rs.id_structure
where
Date(ctr.date) = ISNULL(?,Today())
or
Date(rs.enddate) = ISNULL(?,Today())
GROUP BY crt.contrat
```

The `CASE` statement can be replaced by using `ISNULL` to get a default value for null input and using it in the comparison. If parameter is non-null, you compare the parameter value, else you compare today's date.

Comment: Seems like he doesn't like getdate()...So I tried DATE(NOW()) as I was used to and it didn't work either. I think the condition is working though

Comment: OK, I don't have SSRS on hand so I can't test, but this should give you an idea of how to do it. Where are you calling this query exactly?

Comment: This is a report, so it populates my dataset. The dataset fills the report with the appropriate data. So we want to have only the contract from a specific date. So the first time we execute the report we want to show the now() or curdate() value and let the user choose another date if he wants to.

Comment: OK, I edited my post to use `Today` function instead. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Still gives me an error : Failure executing the query for dataset 'myDataset'. SQL0204 : TODAY of Type *N in *LIBL not found.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to say how and where exactly you are calling this particular query? Is this part of a user defined function, or stored procedure or what is it?